# jQuery, ajax. Как повторно вызвать ajax запрос в ajaxError функции, если он был прерван?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте,

Есть задача, повторно вызвать любой ajax вызов который был прерван в error обработчике. Проблема в том, что при повторном вызове этого запроса не срабатывает done сallback.

Примерный код:

```
// any ajax call
$.ajax(/** params **/).done(function(response) {console.log("success");})

// global ajax error handler
$(document).ajaxError(function (jqXHR, status, error)) {
   $.ajax(error);//как вызвать здесь done из ajax запроса выше в случае его повторного успешного выполнения?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax()` возвращает [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Promise перезапустить невозможно. Единственный выход, обернуть код, который делает ajax-вызов в функцию и вызывать её в `.ajaxError()`.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение